# Design for mutiConsumer System

Tags: design-patterns, factory-pattern

My System will receive feeds from 40 other Systems in future. At present its taking feed from 2 systems.

We are using factory design pattern to handle the processing of various feeds. Eventually in this approach I will be having 40 classes and a huge chain of if-else blocks.

I personally do not think this is a good design. Can any one sight me an alternative design to this ? What design pattern can be thought of to make a robust and strategic design to cater to such requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Chain of responsibility design pattern. It might help you get rid of 40 else if statements. If current class can handle the feed it will else it will delegate the feed to the next FeedHandler class.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/chain_of_responsibility_pattern.htm

Answer (score 0):

On further research I found best way to serve this are below

1. Command pattern where I can store the CommandImpls in a Map. That is GenericImpl should contain all generic actions. Rest of the CommandImpls will extend the generic one.
2. Use Spring integration/Camel to orchestrate the flow. So that You can concentrate only on Impls not the maintenance of the same.
3. To handle a scenario where Impls are likely to Increase in future -Factory pattern is a clear NO NO.